# Xcode build error, sys/_types/_int8_h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode

When I builded my ios project with xcode. I get the following error, how can I fix it:
[image]

Comment: did your tried the solution provided by XCode ?

Comment: I tried it, but I don't have the permission to modify it. The files are system files, have beed locked